# Can I change the language for the Android Market website?

Tags: google-play-store

I've just visited the android market website from my work computer and the website is displaying in German. For what it's worth, I have an Ubuntu box and tried in both Firefox and Chrome (both browsers have en_GB as the first language preference followed by en). I suspect the website tries to be clever and uses my IP address instead of the browser's language settings - all PCs at work (no matter which country) are set to a German IP range.

Is there a request parameter I can add to the URL (or something else) that will force the language to English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the language parameter to the end of the url:    https://market.android.com/?hl=en&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit of searching I have found a (strange) workaround.

In the browser language settings add an unsupported language at the bottom of the list (I chose Faroese because I thought the chances of market support were slim) and then restart the browser. At this point the market website will display in English for me.